# Como puedo hacer un select * from con distinct pero mostrando la tabla completa

Tags: oracle

Tengo esta senetencia SQL `select distinct ID_DOCUMENTO from DOWNLOAD order by ID_DOCUMENTO;`  la cual me muestra solo una ves los datos de cada fila que tienen el ID_DOCUMENTO duplicado pero solo me muestra esa columna y necesito mostrar la tabla completa evitando mostrar datos que tienen el id duplicado

Comment: Suigero que pongas un ejemplo de los datos que hay en la tabla y la salida que esperas obtener con esos datos, además de indicar la versión de oracle con la que trabajas.

Comment: De la tabla espero todos los datos y el distinct lo necesito para evitar mostrar los duplicado en ID_DOCUMENTO mi versión de oracle es: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production

Comment: la descripción que das es confusa, por eso sugiero que pongas una pequeña muestra de datos. Por ejemplo, no sé si para dado `ID` todos los otros campos tamibén tienen un dato exactamente igual en todas las filas donde se presente, o no. La solución es diferente si lo son, que si no lo son.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias posibles soluciones para este problema:

- Si todas las columnas tienen el mismo valor para cada `id_documento`, puedes aplicar el modificador distinct a todas las columnas:

  ```
    select distinct *
      from download;
  ```

  Otra variante es incluir solamente los campos que te interesan. Esta tendría la ventaja de excluir aquellos cuya *variación* pueda ser una llave primaria que se auto-incrementa

  ```
    select distinct id_documento, campo2, campo3, campo4
      from download;
  ```
- Si los datos de las columnas difieren, una forma de lograr lo que quieres sería obtener el *primer registro* de cada `id_documento`, para ello, puedes valerte primero de un `CTE`, usando la función de ventana `row_number()` para numerar los registros, creando particiones por `id_documento` y luego, en la consulta principal, quedarte solo con aquellos que tengan el número de registro 1:

  ```
    with
    base as (
    select ID_DOCUMENTO, campo2, campo3, campo4, row_number() over (partition by ID_DOCUMENTO order by campo2, campo3, campo4) NumRegistro
      from DOWNLOAD 
    )
    select ID_DOCUMENTO, campo2, campo3, campo4
      from base
     where NumRegistro = 1
  ```
- Si la tabla tiene una llave primaria simple, puedes obtener el valor de la llave primaria para la primera aparición de cada id_documento y filtrar por ese campo, por ejemplo

  ```
    with
    base as (
    select id_documento, min(campollave) llave
      from DOWNLOAD
     group by id_documento
    )
    select *
      from download
     where campollave in (select llave from base)
  ```

  Otra alternativa sería hacer un join (habría que evaluar los planes para ver cuál ofrece mejor rendimiento, por eso incluyo las dos en la respuesta):

  ```
    with
    base as (
    select id_documento, min(campollave) llave
      from DOWNLOAD
     group by id_documento
    )
    select download.*
      from download
           inner join base on base.llave = download.campollave
  ```